# Scripts: copy only the part between two specified lines

Tags: bash, vim, awk

E.g.

A file `a.txt` has the following context

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
eee
```

What's the script that could achieve this goal, such that

`script.sh a.txt 2 4`

output:

```
bbb
ccc
ddd
```

Where 2 and 4 are the specified line numbers.

Comment: What, you were able to associate this with `awk` (tag), but couldn't figure out how to do this simple task with it?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `awk` for this:

```
awk 'NR>=2 && NR<=4' file
```

In general,

```
awk -v beginning=$first -v end=$last 'NR>=beginning && NR<=end' $file
```

so it is a matter of reading `$file`, `$first` and `$last` in your script.

---

#### Update:

Based on [doubleDown comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17046819/scripts-copy-only-the-part-between-two-specified-lines/17046863#comment24649792_17046863) (thanks!), it can also be done like this:

```
awk 'NR==2, NR==4' file
```

and more general:

```
awk -v beginning=$first -v end=$last 'NR==beginning, NR==end' $file
```

Comment: Wow! `awk` never stops amazing me with its powerful. Thanks @doubleDown for the comment!

Answer (score 5):

`sed` is a primitive tool that handles this well:

```
sed -n '2,4p' file          # method 1
sed '2,4!d' file            # method 2
```

See the [sed1line.txt](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sed1line.txt); a great resource for `sed` one-liners.

Answer (score 3):

The most concise way to do this is with `sed`:

```
$ sed '2,4!d' file
bbb
ccc
ddd
```

Answer (score 0):

Best choice is to use awk or sed as mentioned.
If you like to use only traditional utils, you can make such trick (where $FILE is a.txt):

```
#!/bin/env bash
FILE=a.txt
SIZE=`wc -l $FILE`
let STARTPOS=$SIZE-$1
let OFFSET=$2-$1
cat $FILE | tail -n $STARTPOS | head -n $OFFSET
```

Comment: I'd say awk and sed are "traditional utils."

Comment: `awk` and `sed` existed for more than 30 years, you can hardly get more "traditional" than that. Your method is unnecessarily convoluted.